# Overlapping of custom Widget in ScrollView GridLayout in Kivy

Tags: python, widget, kivy, scrollview, overlap

this is a trial code that I want to implement in my final project.

**Python Code:**

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6') 
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder

class Wid(BoxLayout):

    def settxt(self,i):
        lab = self.ids['lab']
        but = self.ids['but']
        lab.text = "Label Number {}".format(i)
        but.text = "Button Number {}".format(i)


class Win1(Screen):
    i=0
    def addw(self):
        box1 = self.ids['box1']
        self.i = self.i +1
        w = Wid()
        w.settxt(self.i)
        box1.add_widget(w)

    def switch(self):
        sm.current="win2"


class Win2(Screen):
    def switch(self):
        sm.current="win1"

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("test.kv")
sm = WindowManager()

screens = [Win1(name="win1"), Win2(name="win2")]
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)

sm.current = "win1"

class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

**Kivy Code:**

```
<Wid>:
    lab:lab
    but:but
    BoxLayout:
        height: self.minimum_height
        size: root.size
        Label:
            id: lab

        Button:
            id: but


<Win1>
    name:"win1"
    box1:box1
    BoxLayout:
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: 1,0.2
            Button:
                text:"window 2"
                on_release:
                    root.switch()

            Button:
                text:"add wid"
                on_release:
                    root.addw()

        ScrollView:
            GridLayout:
                id:box1
                orientation: "vertical"
                spacing: 2
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height  
                row_default_height: 60
                cols:1

<Win2>
    name: "win2"

    BoxLayout:
        id: bl

        height: bl.minimum_height
        size_hint_y: None
        Button:
            text:"window 2"
            on_release:
                root.switch()
```

With the press of the switch, I expect that my custom widget to get in the gridlayout in the scrollview, one below the other. But instead, each new widget appears in the last cell of the layout and overlaps on the previous one and empty cells keep on forming above them.
Don't know where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have moved the kv to a separate file, and dynamically created the screens.
Key points: I add the screens dynamically in on_start, this is after the build has completed.  I create the ScreenManager in kv, and use the id to add the screens.  In the kv code I put the ScreenManger in a BoxLayout.  This is a personal preference.  I do this so when accessing objects the root widget is not the screen manager.  Therefore in the switch() methods, the addressing uses the assigned id, rather than relying on the root widget being a screenmanager.

FWIW: If the switch code is only going to change screens I would move those single lines into KV.

```
import kivy

kivy.require('1.0.6')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen


class Wid(BoxLayout):  # Change to layout
    def settxt(self, i):
        lab = self.ids['lab']
        but = self.ids['but']
        lab.text = "Label Number {}".format(i)
        but.text = "Button Number {}".format(i)


class Win1(Screen):
    i = 0

    def addw(self):
        box1 = self.ids['box1']
        self.i = self.i + 1
        w = Wid()
        w.settxt(self.i)
        box1.add_widget(w)

    @staticmethod
    def switch():
        app = App.get_running_app()
        app.root.ids.sm.current = "win2"


class Win2(Screen):
    @staticmethod
    def switch():
        app = App.get_running_app()
        app.root.ids.sm.current = "win1"


class WidgetQ1App(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('widgetq.kv')

    def on_start(self):
        screens = [Win1(name="win1"), Win2(name="win2")]
        sm = self.root.ids.sm
        for screen in screens:
            sm.add_widget(screen)


WidgetQ1App().run()
```

And the KV code:

```
<Wid>:               # Put widgets in a layout, not a widget.
    lab:lab
    but:but
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        Label:
            id: lab

        Button:
            id: but


<Win1>
    # name:"win1"
    box1:box1
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: 1,0.2
            Button:
                text:"window 2"
                on_release:
                    root.switch()

            Button:
                text:"add wid"
                on_release:
                    root.addw()

        ScrollView:
            GridLayout:
                id:box1
                orientation: "vertical"
                spacing: 2
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                row_default_height: 60
                cols:1

<Win2>:
    # name: "win2"
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text:"window 2"
            on_release:
                root.switch()
BoxLayout:
    ScreenManager:
        id: sm
```

Comment: Thanks, now the code works all right. But I still haven't got how my code was wrong or how is the dynamic screen helps. Will this method work when using screens where **on_pre_enter()** is also used?

Comment: The biggest issue in your original code was that class Wid(Widget) was used.  You were putting objects in a Widget, rather than into a layout.  I created the screens in Python to match what you had done in your original code.  You can add an on_pre_enter= into the screen constructor, much like you did with the screen name.   Put in into the definition of the screen in kv.  You can move the instancing of the screens to kv.

Answer (score 0):

```
<win2>
    name: "win2"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: bl.minimum_height
    BoxLayout:
        id: bl
        Button:
            text:"window 2"
            on_release:
                root.switch()
```

Your custom widgets don't have a height defined, try changing to something like the above.

Also, start your class names with an upper case letter, kv requires this in some cases. For instance, `win2` should be `Win2`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I have made the necessary changes to class names and height. Still,  those widgets are overlapping.

Comment: Updated, also when I try the code without * size:size.root*, there is a double instantiation of my custom widget in BoxLayout.

Comment: According to your updated code, you haven't made the fix I explained.

Comment: Please try to run the update code, there is a problem of double instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

A number of issues here, see the comments.  The biggest problem I see is putting items in a widget.  Put Widgets in a layout, not other widgets.

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = """
<Wid>:               # Put widgets in a layout, not a widget.
    lab:lab
    but:but
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        Label:
            id: lab

        Button:
            id: but


<Win1>
    # name:"win1"
    box1:box1
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: 1,0.2
            Button:
                text:"window 2"
                on_release:
                    root.switch()

            Button:
                text:"add wid"
                on_release:
                    root.addw()

        ScrollView:
            GridLayout:
                id:box1
                orientation: "vertical"
                spacing: 2
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height  
                row_default_height: 60
                cols:1

<Win2>:
    # name: "win2"
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text:"window 2"
            on_release:
                root.switch()
ScreenManager:
    id: sm
    Win1:
        name: 'win1'
    Win2:
        name: 'win2'

"""


class Wid(BoxLayout):       # Change to layout
    def settxt(self,i):
        lab = self.ids['lab']
        but = self.ids['but']
        lab.text = "Label Number {}".format(i)
        but.text = "Button Number {}".format(i)


class Win1(Screen):
    i = 0

    def addw(self):
        box1 = self.ids['box1']
        self.i = self.i + 1
        w = Wid()
        w.settxt(self.i)
        box1.add_widget(w)

    @staticmethod
    def switch():
        app = App.get_running_app()
        app.root.current = "win2"


class Win2(Screen):
    @staticmethod
    def switch():
        app = App.get_running_app()
        app.root.current = "win1"

# class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
#     pass

# kv = Builder.load_file("test.kv")
# sm = WindowManager()
#
# screens = [win1(name="win1"), win2(name="win2")]
# for screen in screens:
#     sm.add_widget(screen)
#
# sm.current = "win1"


class WidgetQApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


WidgetQApp().run()
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly as I wish mine should run. For now, I have made the changes you have indicated in the comments, now there is no overlapping but there is an additional instantiation of a blank boxlayout in my widget. Please try running my code to see for yourself.

Comment: Post your updated code.  What do you want to change in the code I posted?

Comment: I have updated the code in the question itself. Actually I am testing the custom widget to use later in my actual project. The actual project is way big to use the string loader method, so I want to so with the separate .kv file method.

Comment: I have responded with another answer.